Is it a good idea to pursue a postdoc in robotics before switching to industry?
I graduated with PhD in Europe in 2023 in a very theoretical field (control systems and applied math) and have been a postdoc since. I am now convinced that I need to move to the industry, and I am also convinced that I am looking at a future in motion control/robotics. However, when I apply for jobs I'm invariably rejected due to my lack of 'hands on' experience with programming and robots. I have mostly worked so far in mathematically sound with minimal reliance on simulations, so it has been hard to sell myself.
I am not in an environment where I can do any applied research. So I am wondering if doing another postdoc in robotics will help me build these skills and get some applied experience. I am not sure if doing another postdoc will suck me into the academic world when I want to get out of it, or if industry will see multiple postdocs as a red flag or a gain in experience. Some advice here is appreciated

The number of jobs in 'robotic control systems' is a subset of the number of jobs in 'robotics' - how well tuned have your applications been to control systems? Have you applied to non-robotic control system jobs?

This seems to be about industry jobs, not about academia.

Why not explore a postdoc in industry?

@Buffy it's a question about an exit route from academia. While I agree that the focus is "what will industry want", in today's academic climate I think it's a very relevant thing to cover here. (I'm not sure this is a good question for other reasons, though ;-))

Computer science professor here. If you are certain that you want to go to industry, then you should be focusing much of your time on developing the concrete skills required for your chosen path, building your network, and applying for many jobs. In the meanwhile, feel free to secure another postdoc so that you still have income, and do carry out the tasks required of you in that postdoc job, but don't let it eat up 100% of your time.
There are many ways to get hands-on experience in robotics without a postdoc in robotics. For example, at my university, our systems courses have students working with arduino robots. The university where you are currently a postdoc probably has some of those (or, if not, a budget to buy them so students can get hands-on experience), and you could get involved. Many universities also have a club where students can sharpen their robotics skills, e.g., a RoboCup league. You could get involved as a mentor to such a group. Heck, even the local high school might have such a club.
You should also get on GitHub and share software you have written, to show employers that you are able to put theory into practice. Full-on research, leading to conference publications, is probably more than you need to do in order to showcase your expertise in robotics. Applied projects on GitHub can show the same and are much easier to carry out, even in your current role. Lastly, apply widely and for more jobs than you think you need to. It is not that easy to step from academia to industry, so be persistent.

Thank you for your answer, it is very helpful! Unfortunately, I don't see any avenue where I am currently to pursue these skills, and a contract extension is unlikely to happen, and hence considering another position where at least I can hone some relevant skills. Caveat is that there's possibly a minimum commitment time to hold as it requires securing a project and collaborating on some papers, in addition to of course teaching and administration. So it would be another few months before I can start looking for jobs, but hope that it is enough for me to get some hands-on experience.
